# Adding javascript function inside a php function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I got a html table filled with data from db. When i click on the table i need to call the below script that will get the data from the clicked table row and pass it on a form which is present on csv_info.php

Error :  ReferenceError: callAJAX is not defined at 
                      HTMLTableCellElement.onclick 
My thoughts  : scoping issue, but cant seem to find a fix for this

````php
$c_onclik="onclick=\"
                              window.scrollTo(1, 1);document.getElementById('a_rlt_1').className = 'Active'; 
                              document.getElementById('i_box_930').style.display='block';
                              callAJAX('csv_info.php?csv_id=".$result['uploadlisteid']."', 'infowin2', '', '');
                              \"";
```
````

Comment: where is `callAJAX` function defined? apparently the rest of the script is running OK in the browser,  so you got that part right, you just haven't got a function called `callAJAX`

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to add JavaScript via PHP, but you can. You must know that PHP executes immediately before your page is sent to the Client's Browser, so that PHP `$result['uploadlisteid']` will only happen when the page loads. What you want to do is make an AJAX call to the Server, using JavaScript to get your PHP results.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is part of and old page and in the old page (php version ~3 ) the code works perfectly. callAJAX is not defined anywhere else.

Comment: Full page code if someone needs it : https://jsfiddle.net/9buto7fs/

Comment: @DenisXheleku I havent gone thru it all (from your jsfiddle) but on cursory glance your code `<?php $c_onclik; ?>` is doing absolutely nothing.